# SQL query to join multiple tables to meet all conditions or nothing in return

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this scenario and result set for my query. I need to filter the result set using certain condition.

Query I have:

```
SELECT 
ord_no,parent_item,child_item,status

FROM **TABLE1** WHERE parent_item IN ('ITEM1') AND ord_no IN ('12345','34567','67854')

UNION ALL

SELECT 
ord_no,parent_item,child_item,status

FROM **TABLE2** WHERE parent_item IN ('ITEM2') AND ord_no IN ('12345','34567','67854')

UNION ALL

SELECT 
ord_no,parent_item,child_item,status

FROM **TABLE3** WHERE parent_item IN ('ITEM3') AND ord_no IN ('12345','34567','67854')
```

The query returns result like this and expected result that I am looking for is to return only that specific order_no where  ALL child_items are in COMPLETE status.

Query Result:

```
ord_no parent_item child_item status
12345   item1   childA  complete
12345   item1   childB  complete
12345   item2   childC  complete
12345   item2   childD  incomplete
12345   item3   childE  incomplete
12345   item3   childF  complete

34567   item1   childA  complete
34567   item1   childB  complete
34567   item2   childC  complete
34567   item2   childD  complete
34567   item3   childE  complete
34567   item3   childF  complete

67854   item1   childA  incomplete
67854   item1   childB  incomplete
67854   item2   childC  complete
67854   item2   childD  complete
67854   item3   childE  incomplete
67854   item3   childF  incomplete
```

Expected Result:

I am not able to figure out how do I implement this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
ord_no parent_item child_item status

34567   item1   childA  complete
34567   item1   childB  complete
34567   item2   childC  complete
34567   item2   childD  complete
34567   item3   childE  complete
34567   item3   childF  complete
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide 1) relevant parts of your actual table schemas along with sample data 2) the exact desired output 3) your attempt so far

Comment: Believe if you don't have your actual table structure ready, you can not expect us to help you with query on imagination

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) from your existing query to avoid long expressions and use it for subqueries.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView 
WHERE ord_no NOT IN
  (SELECT ord_no
  FROM MyView
  WHERE status <> 'complete');
```